# Setting a slash on cookie path?

Tags: cookies

Is there a best practice whether to set a slash at the end of a cookie path?
Is
`path`
better than
`path/`
in any way?
I found out that both versions result in different cookies, but I don't know which version is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the server-side goes, this issue (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=469678) states:

> Per RFC 2109 the default path of a cookie when set by Set-Cookie is:
>
> Defaults to the path of the request URL that generated the Set-Cookie response, up to, but not including, the right-most /.

So this is one perspective where a trailing slash should not be used.

---

### RFC History

#### RFC 2109, February 1997, HTTP State Management Mechanism

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109

- See *4.3.1  Interpreting Set-Cookie*
- Defaults to the path of the request URL that generated the Set-Cookie response, up to, but not including, the right-most /.

**DON'T** include trailing '/'.

#### RFC 2965, October 2000, HTTP State Management Mechanism

Obsoletes: 2109

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965

- See *3.3.1  Interpreting Set-Cookie2*
- Defaults to the path of the request URL that generated the Set-Cookie2 response, up to and including the right-most /.

**DO** include trailing '/'.

#### RFC 6265, April 2011, HTTP State Management Mechanism

Obsoletes: 2965

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.4

- See *5.1.4.  Paths and Path-Match*
- -3.  If the uri-path contains no more than one %x2F ("/") character, output %x2F ("/") and skip the remaining step.
- -4.  Output the characters of the uri-path from the first character up to, but not including, the right-most %x2F ("/").

**DON'T** include trailing '/'.

---

### Client test

On the client, if you use the following code:

```
document.cookie="a=1"
```

you get these results from inspecting devtools for each browser (my site had a window.location.pathname="**/selenium/tests/testCustomizeColumnsPage.html**")

```
Chrome/71.0.3578   /selenium/tests
Firefox/64.0       /selenium/tests/
Edge               /selenium/tests/
IE11               devtools doesn't show cookies, think the path includes the trailing '/'
```

So is Chrome wrong here?

---

Other references:

- https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie/commit/d78d3a3593d1aea1d821d45492297ddf2e990568
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=414582
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=469678
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=537207

Comment: You forgot to mention that RFC6265 paragraphs 5.1.4. relates to **user agent** default-path computing algorithm, not server response. It is not something that server could not send. See also path grammar `path-value = <any CHAR except CTLs or ";">`

Comment: Firefox/64 indeed does set a trailing slash. But Firefox/69 doesn't! After upgrading firefox, our clients now have two cookies. One for `/path/` (from old versions) and `/path` (from new versions). Great!

Answer (score 1):

No, in general you should not put a slash at the end of the cookie path. The only exception is for cookies targeting the root folder, where you should write:

```
path=/
```

For subfolders, you should normally write (for example):

```
path=/Content/Web
```

Why? Most web servers consider that these three requests all point to the same file:

```
GET /Content/Web
GET /Content/Web/
GET /Content/Web/index.html
```

If your cookie has a trailing slash like `/Content/Web/` then it won't be sent to the first request above. This may lead to confusing application behavior. A cookie without a trailing slash like `/Content/Web` will cover all three requests.

Answer (score 0):

We've just seen a bug in Safari on Iphone where cookies set without a trailing slash were empty. The bug affects one of the three Iphones I have in front of me, an Iphone 7 running IOS 11.3.1. In devtools, we can see the name of the cookie, but the value is not there. The same issue seems to have hit [this user](https://github.com/shaarli/Shaarli/issues/615). We're putting trailing slashes on cookie pathes now !

Comment: Noticed the same effect with IE 11. Though there doesn't seem to be a way to inspect the saved cookies, they just weren't read if set with trailing slash.